# iTextSharp merging PDF's without persisting page size

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have the following piece of .NET code to merge two PDFs via iTextSharp.

```
        byte[] result;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, ms))
                    doc.Open();
                    var d1 = new PdfReader(coverSheetPdf);
                    copy.AddDocument(d1);
                    var d2 = new PdfReader(reportPdf);
                    copy.AddDocument(d2);
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            result = ms.ToArray();
        }
```

The above merges a Letter/Landscape PDF with a Tabloid/Landscape PDF.  In most cases the page size of each PDF is maintained however in certain cases the merged document is all one size.

The image below shows the page sizes when in Debug
[image: Page sizes]

I have attached the following files

- Coversheet file: represented by variable d1 in the code
  (http://www.mediafire.com/file/be4x8fzyqle6hdt/Coversheet.pdf/file)
- Report file: represented by variable d1 in the code
  (http://www.mediafire.com/file/8z5q260h8j32b6l/Report.pdf/file)
- Merged file of both of the above
  (http://www.mediafire.com/file/5ob79holw3yfaz7/Merged_Coversheet%252BReport.pdf/file)

Any ideas why the merged PDF contains pages all the same size?

Comment: Please post the PDFs and the resulting PDF that is all one size.

Comment: Indeed, `PdfCopy` by its architecture should make sure that the copied pages retain their dimensions. At worst I'd assume an issue with inherited attributes...

Comment: Many thanks for the reply - PDF's added to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - this was a false alarm - it was due some post-processing - after the merge was being performed there was page numbering of each page (performed by iTextSharp) which defaulted the page sizes to the first page's size

Comment: *" there was page numbering of each page (performed by iTextSharp) which defaulted the page sizes to the first page's size"* - that sounds like a dumb page numbering implementation. The natural iTextSharp implementation would simply have used a `PdfStamper` and stamped the respective page number on each page...